# Promise injection Dagger

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm wondering if there is a way in Dagger to promise that a dependency will be provided at runtime? In my case, I have package A which cannot depend on anything in package B, but a Dagger component in package A depends on a module which contains a method which takes in an interface which has a dependency provided in B. If I can't promise that the dependency will be there at runtime, is there anything else I can do to get around this without making package B accessible to A using other dagger Techniques? I'm wondering if maybe `@BindsOptionalOf` annotation could be of any use. Here is a code representation:

```
@Component (modules = {ModuleA.class, ModuleB.class})
@Singleton
public interface ComponentA {

  AObject getA();

}
```

```
@Module
public abstract class ModuleA{

    @Provides
    static XInterface provideX(InterfaceB b) {
        return new XImpl(b);
    }
}
```

```
@Module
public abstract class ModuleB{

  @Binds
  abstract InterfaceB bindB (BImpl impl);
}
```

Where ModuleB is inaccessible to componentA or moduleA, but interfaceB is.

Thank you!

Comment: Simplest solution might be a [component factory](https://dagger.dev/api/2.36/dagger/Component.Factory.html) or builder where you pass in the implementation

Comment: Hi @DavidMedenjak, I'm not totally sure I understand how a component factory helps? Wouldn't I still need access to the dependency in module B, which this wouldn't give to component A?

Comment: Dagger2 does the magic at build time (which is a good thing).  Make a build per deployment. If you cannot do that use another DI framework like spring or guice.